# Prove no existing a smooth function satisfying ... related to Morse Theory

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-topology, morse-theory

i) Show that there does not exist a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, s.t. $f(x) \geq 0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ has ***exactly two critical points***, $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2) = 0$. (This part is easy).

ii) Show that there does not exist a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, s.t. $f(x,y) \geq 0$, $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ has ***exactly two critical points***, $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2) = 0$.

I have tried several methods, however, it does not work, could anybody help me out?

Comment: Just wondering, did you put the topology tag on your question because of the smooth function requirement, or because of something else?

Comment: Actually, it's a problem from topology class. It may be related to the tangent spaces, but I am not so sure. I have looked through the book: Topology from the differentiable viewpoints, however, still having no idea.

Comment: Part 2 holds for proper functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here a counterexample to 2) (without "properness" assumptions)

Let $B$ the ball of center $0$ and radius $1$.

Let $g:B\to\mathbb R$ be a function with property 2) (positive with two minima where the function is zero and no other critical point). 
This is easily constructed.

Now consider any diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to B$.

Now the function $f=g(\phi(x))$ has the requested properties.

To build $g$ consider a smooth positive function $h$ with isolated critical poitns  and two minima $p_1$ and $p_2$ where $h=0$. Now join $p_1$ to $p_2$ with a simple arc which avoids critical points other than the $p_i$. A regular neighborood of such arc is a disc $D$ where $h$ has no critical points other than at $p_1$ and $p_2$.      Now uses a diffeomorphism from $B$ to $D$ and compose with $h$.

**EDIT** from the comment of  "This is much healthier": Begin with $g(x,y)=(x^2−1)^2+y^2$, take any simply-connected domain that contains the minima $(\pm 1,0)$ but not the saddle point $(0,0)$, and map that domain onto $R^2$ by a diffeomorphism. (The domain can be chosen of convenient starlike shape, so that the diffeomorphism can be given explicitly.)

**EDIT on "properness" assumptions** (for those that have "topology from a differential viewpoint" in their hands.)

Consider a ball $B_R$ centered at $(0,0)$ and of radius $R$. Let $V$ be the gradient vector field of $f$. By the theorem on the indices of zeors of vector fields, we known that

1) if $V$ points outward $B_R$ at its boundary, then the sum of the indices of the zeroes of $V$ equals the characteristic of $B_R$ which is $1$. Since minima contribute with $+1$, if $f$ has two minima it must have at least another critical point with index $-1$   (for instance a saddle).

2) if $V$ does not points outward $B_R$ at its boundary, then the sum of indices is the degree of the map $\partial B_R\to S^1$ given by $V/||V||$.

So if you assume that there is $R$ so that $V$ points outward $B_R$ at its boundary, then $f$ must have another critical point. On the other hand this tells you that with the above construction of an $f$ with only two minima, there is no $R$ such that the two minima are contained in $B_R$ AND $V=grad(f)$ points outward $B_R$ at its boundary.

In conclusion, everything depends on the degree of $V/||V||$ on big circles.

Also, you could replace $B_R$ with level sets. Suppose there is a simple closed curve $C$, contained in  a level set (of a regular value) for $f$. By Jordan theorem $C$ bounds a disc $D$. Moreover, since $C$ is in a level set, the gradient vector field $V$ points always either inward or outward $D$ at $C$.

Thus the sum of indices of critical points in $D$ is $1$. So,

**Fact**: $D$ contains at least a critical point and if it contains two minima, it must contains also a third critical point.

In particular, one can use that to prove **2) if one adds the assumption that $f$ is proper**, that is to say, $f$-preimages of compact sets are compact. (which is equivalent to the requirement that $\lim_{p\to\infty}f(p)=\infty$.)

In this case, suppose such an $f$ exists, let $B$ a ball containing the two critical points and let $K=100\sup_Bf$. $K$ is a regular value of $f$ because $f$ has only the two minima in $B$. Thus $f^{-1}(K)$ is a $1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$. It is compact because $f$ is proper. Let $C$ be a connected component of $f^{-1}(K)$. $C$ does not intersect $B$ because of the choice of $K$. On the other hand, $C$ bounds a disc $D$ (by Jordan theorem).

Then, by the above **Fact**, if $D$ contains $B$ than it must contains a third critical point, and if $D$ does not contain $B$ then it contains a critical point which is different from the two minima in $B$. Therefeore $f$ must have at least three critical points.

Comment: Why do you think $p_1, p_2$ are in the same component of the set of regular points of the function $h$? (They need not be!)

Comment: just build a particular function $h$ with isolated critical points: now the complement of the critical points is connected.

Comment: Oh, of course, by taking a Morse function.

Comment: @studiosus, I mean such a function is easy to construct explicitly

Comment: yes, morse-like functions do the job

Comment: Edit: added that the sentence on isolated critical point

Comment: Very nice. A slight variation of your argument: begin with $g(x,y) = (x^2-1)^2+y^2$, take any simply-connected domain that contains the minima $(\pm 1,0)$ but not the saddle point $(0,0)$, and map that domain onto $\mathbb R^2$ by a diffeomorphism. (The domain can be chosen of convenient starlike shape, so that the diffeomorphism can be given explicitly).

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. yes I should have build explicitly the function $h$ and skip the passage from $B$, as you suggest.

Comment: @ user126154. Thank you very much. However, if properness assumptions are added, it seems that the same construction also holds. Also, if the properness assumptions are added, the conclusion of the question seems reasonable. So, how could we resolve this contradiction. Is there anything wrong for this?

Comment: well, if you are reading "topology from the differential veiw point", then with some properness hypothesis you see that the sum of indices of the zeroes of the gradient vector field gives you the characteristic of the disc, which is 1. Since minima contributes with +1 each, you need at least another critical point, say a saddle...

Comment: @user126154. Thank you for your quick reply. This is just what I am confusing about. On one hand, as you said, by the theorem from "topology from the differential view point", when proper assumptions are added, the question seems right. However, on the other hand, when proper assumptions are added, the same construction also holds the same as you proposed, which means that the question is not correct. Actually, intuitively, if the neighborhood is chosen starlike shape, the boundary is not so smooth, I am wondering whether there exists a diffeomorphism from this starlike shape to B.

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons the consctuction will not satisfies the right properness assumptions.

Comment: @user126154. Thank you. Actually, I mean that if we are given a specific nonnegative smooth function $f$ such that the critical points are isolated and there are exactly two minima with value 0, for example, we can choose $f(x,y) =[(x+1)^2 + y^2][(x-1)^2+y^2] $ which satisfies the properness assumption for the two minima. Then by the same construction as you proposed, it should be that the conclusion of the problem is not correct. However, on the other hand, the constructed function for this specific function also satisfies the properness assumption, then there is a contradiction. Why?

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons If I understand what you say, the answer is that the final function we construct  is not proper, as it is bounded. Indeed, if we take a disk $D$ containing the two minima, then $f$ is bounded on $D$ and so is the $f(\phi(x))$, where $\phi$ is the diffeo from $\mathbb R^2$ and $D$.

Comment: @user126154. Thank you for your reply. Sorry, it's not what I mean. I mean that if for a specific smooth function, such as $f(x,y)=[(x+1)^2 + y^2][(x-1)^2 + y^2]$, we can also construct a function following the same method your proposed. Now, we have a contradiction, on the one hand, as you argued, the constructed function has exactly two critical pts, i.e. two minimal; on the other hand, the constructed function satisfies the regular assumptions, which means that the critical pts are non-degenerate ones, then applying the Morse Theory, there should exist another critical pts. How to explain?

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons You keep saying that "we can" construct a proper function with such behavior. Why don't you go ahead and do it in detailed way (not in a comment). I think you'll discover that the construction you have in mind does not work.

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons Yesterday I edited the answer, now it contains a complete proof of claim 2) with the properness assumption. So I don't keep saying that "we can" construct a proper function with such behaviour: My answer contains a proof that a proper function with the requirements prescribed in 2) cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your topology instinct is right. If you consider the portion of the graph of $f$ inside a big ball, you will have two minima. If you cap off the boundary of that portion, you will have a topological sphere, with $\chi =2$. The height function has a maximum and two minima, which would give $\chi=3$. (I'm assuming nondegenerate critical points here.)

I'm still pondering an elementary argument. It would be helpful to know what you've learned/proved in your course.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have thought about this idea, however, I think there are two problems here. First of all, the other critical points may be not maximum, for example, saddle point; secondly, if we constraint ourselves to the ball, even though maximum exists, that point may be not critical point. By the way, what are covered in the class are basically point set topology, some algebraic topology, like homotopy, some parts of book, Topology from the differentiable viewpoints.

Comment: No, I'm proposing to take the portion of the graph at some large height $z=R\gg 0$ and cap it off smoothly with a disk lying in $z\ge R$. (This sort of stuff is done all the time in differential topology.) There will be a maximum height by the maximum value theorem on the resulting compact surface. If your course has covered some Morse theory, this is a reasonable solution. (From Milnor's little book, there is no Morse theory, but there is the Poincaré-Hopf Theorem.)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I'm not familiar with differential topology and Morse theory, I will have a look at it later. However, I am wondering if the maximum point is not interior point, is it necessary that point is critical point?

Comment: What I'm talking about is a maximum of the Morse function $F(x,y,z)=z$ on the resulting compact surface. (This is the "height function" to which I referred.) When I cap off the surface, it's of course no longer a graph over the $xy$-plane. I'll be very curious to find out the solution your instructor has in mind!

Comment: One last comment: Basically, what's going on is a non-compact version of Morse theory. If we have a topological disk, the sum of the Morse indices must be the Euler characteristic of the disk, namely $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look through these stuffs later, the Morse theory is not covered in the class.

Comment: I have read one version of Morse theory from wiki as follows: Suppose f is a smooth real-valued function on M, a < b, $f^{−1}[a, b]$ is compact, and there are no critical values between a and b. Then M^a is diffeomorphic to M^b, and M^b deformation retracts onto M^a. If I can find some b such that $f^{−1}[0, b]$ is compact, then the problem can be proven by showing that the set with two distinct points is not a retract from the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ space. Or, is there any other version of Morse theory such that compactness is not necessary? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For the one dimensional case, you need to argue that $f$ assumes a maximum on $[x_1,x_2]$. This must be bigger than $0$ (otherwise all points where zero and critical points), and is a critical point.

The second problem is harder, and I believe it is false without extra assumptions. If you want I can sketch a counterexample.

I would use a variant of the finite dimensional mountain pass lemma, which would require a properness condition on your function. See for example the discussion at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105951/finite-dimensional-mountain-pass-lemma.

Comment: Thank you. It will be great if you can give me a counterexample in detail to show the problem is not correct. Intuitively, I think it's right.

Comment: Yes, I realized a while ago that my topological argument tacitly assumed properness (i.e., $f$ gets big eventually). There is a famous example of a function with a unique critical point, which is a local minimum point, for which there is no global minimum. I haven't convinced myself that could be modified in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As required by "This is much healthier", I post a new thread to express my opinions as related to "user126154"'s answer, which is great, however there is something that I can't convince myself.

First of all, the compactness condition in the proof of "user126154" can be relaxed as proposed in *Richard Palais: Topology Volume 2, Issue 4, 1963*, which can be found here: 
[Richard Palais's paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uocz1ld33vletn8/Topology%20Volume%202%20issue%204%201963%20Richard%20S.%20Palais%20--%20Morse%20theory%20on%20Hilbert%20manifolds.pdf).

Secondly, let's consider the smooth function $h(x,y) = [(x+1)^2 + y^2][(x-1)^2 + y^2]$, it will be easily shown that the critical points are isolated, and the only two minimal are non-degenerate critical points.

Now, on the one hand, just as "user126154" proposed, we can constructed a new function the same way (the details are shown below):

Consider any diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow B$.

For the two minimal of $h$, $(-1,0);(1,0)$ denoted as $p_1,p_2$, now join $p_1$ to $p_2$ with a simple arc which avoids critical points other than the $p_1,p_2$. A regular neighborhood of such arc is a disc D where h has no critical points other than at $p_1$ and $p_2$. Now uses a diffeomorphism $\psi$ from B to D and compose with $h$, which is $h(\psi(\phi(x,y)))$. Then the constructed function should have only two critical points.

On the other hand, if the constructed function is exactly a counterexample, for the reason that the critical points of the constructed function are non-degenerate, we can apply the theorem in the paper above to show that there is at least another critical point.

So, what's the problem?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier,@user126154

Comment: I just realized that the counterexample proposed by "user126154" is actually not a counterexample, because that the constructed function does not attribute the two critical points to 0.